# Gift money from uncle to nephew, from NRE account to Indian saving account

Tags: income-tax, india, gift-tax

If a nephew gets gift money in his saving account from the NRE account of his uncle, how much limit of the gift money should be & whether the gift money is taxable for nephew?

Is it required to be documented?

Comment: Please turn off your CAPS lock.

Comment: Gifts between close relatives are not taxable to the recipient in India and so the answer to your question depends on _exactly how_ your uncle is related to you. A sibling of either of your parents is a close relative for tax purposes but a cousin who is colloquially referred to as a brother in India (more formally called a cousin-brother) is not. So, check your uncle's birth certificate!

Answer (score 2):

From an [India gift-tax point of view](http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/_layouts/15/dit/mobile/faqs/faq-questions.aspx?key=FAQs%20on%20Gifts%20received%20by%20an%20individual%20or%20HUF&k=), you can receive unlimited funds from close relatives. So if you are getting this from your Father's Brother or Mother's Brother; then it is not taxable.

It is a good idea to document this if the amount is large. It serves as record for future. This can be a simple piece of paper or something that's type on Notarized document.